# Calling backend after using Next-Auth and Google oauth

Tags: javascript, laravel, next.js, graphql, next-auth

I have a question that I've been thinking about for a while.

How can I verify user authentication when using the Next-Auth library for OAuth (e.g., Google) in Next.js? I want to call my backend to fetch some data using GraphQL, but I'm unsure how to check at backend if the user is genuinely logged in and if everything is valid and correct. Has anyone encountered this issue before? I would greatly appreciate guidance on how to implement it.

Thank you!

I tried to send some access_tokens and stuff, but then i thought about it and i figured out that i cannot or i don't know how to check if token and everything is valid or its some random string.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.